# BatteryHistory.java: file cannot be found in the master branch of the Android source code

Tags: android, debugging, debug-symbols, android-source

I compiled the master branch and run it in the emulator. The "Battery History" item in the "Spare Parts" menu, does not work. It results in "Force close" of "Spare parts".

DDMS log shows error message like:

```
04-11 11:13:14.080: E/AndroidRuntime(9593): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.battery_history.BatteryHistory}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I found that "Battery History" uses the class `com.android.settings.battery_history.BatteryHistory` but this class does not exist any more. It was in the repository `platform/packages/apps/Settings.git` before. I search the whole code base and couldn't find this class.

Has this file become not open-source any more and been put into some JAR files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

Class `com.android.settings.battery_history.BatteryHistory` has been removed. `android.os.BatteryStats` is used for the similar purpose instead. The SpareParts in the same checkout still uses the outdated `BatteryHistory`, so it didn't work.